# "You or singular noun" should be followed by 3rd person singular or 2nd person?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

> If you or a team member **needs / need** any help during my vacation,
>   please do not hesitate to contact me on my mobile phone.

**Should I write need or needs?**

Comment: This is one of the cases where native speakers tend not to have an intuition about the answer (or at least, not a consistent intuition) so we're thrown back on the "grammarians" who make things up - and they don't all make up the same rule. Neither answer seems 100% right to me, as a native speaker. so if anybody tells you there is a "right" answer, they're making it up, or believing somebody who made it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would go with "needs" like SarahT mentioned in her answer.

Generally, when we have two or more singular nouns or pronouns that are connected by **or** or **nor**, we use a singular verb.

Therefore, I would say

> If you or *a team member* **needs** any help ...

And when we have a compound subject that contains a singular and a plural noun or pronoun connected by **or** or **nor**, we use the verb that agrees with the subject that is closest to the verb. This is what James K referred to in his comment.

If the second subject was plural (= team members), then I would use the plural verb:

> If you or your *team members* **need** any help ...

---

#### **What do authoritative and reputable sources say?**

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS) 17th ed. says

> When a verb has two or more subjects connected by ***and***, it agrees with them jointly and is plural {**Socrates and Plato were** wise}. When a verb has two or more subjects connected by ***or*** or ***nor***, the verb agrees with the last-named subject {**Bob or his friends have** your key} {**neither the twins nor Jon is** prepared to leave}. 
>   — 5.138: Agreement in person and number

This problem may also arise when using an ***either-or*** or ***neither-nor*** construction. The CMoS says that

> ... pronouns joined by ***or,*** ***either–or, or neither–nor*** are traditionally said to take the verb form that agrees with the nearer subject {**either he or I am** in for a surprise} {**either you or he is** right} {**neither you nor I am** a plumber}. — 5.143: Agreement in first and second person

The "supplemental materials" link in [this](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/07/all-or-none.html) APA Style Blog says

> When the subject is composed of a singular and a plural noun joined by **or** or **nor**, the verb agrees with the noun that is closer.

The APA and MLA style guides say the same thing, only I can't quote them because I don't have full access to them. You can look them up online.

Answer (score 1):

When joining a list of singular nouns with "or," use a singular verb. "If you or a team member needs any help..."

Comment: Also apply the  tendency of "closest subject":  "He or you are..."  but "You or he is"

Comment: Alright, but I am asking about "you" or a team member.

Comment: Team member is singular, so the answer applies to it as part of a list of singular nouns.

Comment: Right, technically the 2nd person singular and 2nd person plural of the verb "need" are both "need", so the question could be about singular vs. plural, but it could also be about whether to use the 2nd person singular or the 3rd person singular (what I thought). The right answer is thus the combination of Sarah's and James's answers. Here are some examples from other places: https://www.nimh.nih.gov/site-info/if-you-or-someone-you-know-is-in-crisis-and-needs-immediate-help.shtml, or google "if you or someone you know needs help"

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that the verb in an *or, either/or*, or *neither/nor* sentence agrees with the noun or pronoun closest to it. ([source](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp))

As the verb follows "a team member", it should "**needs**":

> If you or a team member *needs* any help...